# How to send notification to all user except the sender in android using node js firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud functions to send notifications to topics. The problem is that it sends to all users including the sender, while I don't want it to send to the sender. Please don't give a example of subscribe and unsubscribe example as I could not understand this solution. Please help?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

    console.log('Push notification event triggered');


      var  message1 = event.data.val();

      if (!message1) {
          return;
          }
      var valueObject = message1.messageText;


    console.log('Push notification event triggered '+valueObject);

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title:'Chat app',
            body: valueObject,

        },
    };


    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 0 * 0 * 0
    };


    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options).then(function(response) {

   console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
   return event.data.adminRef.vel();
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
   console.log("Error sending message:", error);
 });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you shared is sending to a topic. All subscribers to that topic will receive the message, there is no way to skip one of them. If you want to send to all-but-one users, you will need to have a list of their tokens and know the token of the sender.

Comment: But how can i get all tokens..can u explain please

Comment: You will have to add code to each client that sends the token to the server. The [documentation has a placeholder `sendRegistrationToServer` where you need to do that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation). For a more complete example, see the [first use-case of Cloud Functions for Firebase]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Frank-van-puffelen